# Merge two unrelated views into a single view

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

Let's say I have in my first view `(ClothingID, Shoes, Shirts)`
and in the second view I have `(ClothingID, Shoes, Shirts)` HOWEVER
the data is completely unrelated, even the ID field is not related in anyway.
I want them combined into 1 single view for reporting purposes.
so the 3rd view (the one I'm trying to make) should look like this: `(ClothingID, ClothingID2, Shoes, Shoes2, Shirts, Shirts2)`
so there's no relation AT ALL, I'm just putting them side by side, unrelated data into the same view.

Any help would be strongly appreciated

Comment: If there is no relation, why do you want to join them? And: *how* ? Cartesian product?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging 2 views together into 1 view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118997/merging-2-views-together-into-1-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to **combine** the results, yet be able to tell the rows **apart**.
To duplicate all columns would be a bit of an overkill. Add a column with info about the source:

```
SELECT 'v1'::text AS source, clothingid, shoes, shirts
FROM   view1

UNION  ALL
SELECT 'v2'::text AS source, clothingid, shoes, shirts
FROM   view2;
```

Comment: I was scratching my head today and I figured, hey I'm silly, I should just be making another column that says the source, I looked back at my answers and saw that you showed how to do this, and I'm like, THIS IS IT! thanks

Comment: @user519753: Sometimes things are hidden in plain sight. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
select v1.ClothingID, v2.ClothingID as ClothingID2, v1.Shoes, v2.Shoes as Shoes2,
    v1.Shirts, v2.Shirts as Shirts2
from (
    select *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ClothingID) AS row
    from view_1
) v1
full outer join (
    select *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ClothingID) AS row
    from view_2
) v2 on v1.row = v2.row
```

I think that `full outer join`  that joins table using new unrelated column `row` will do the job.

`row_number()` exists in [PostgreSQL 8.4 and above](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html).

If you have lower version you can imitate `row_number`, example below. It's going to work only if `ClothingID` is unique in a scope of view.

```
select v1.ClothingID, v2.ClothingID as ClothingID2, v1.Shoes, v2.Shoes as Shoes2,
    v1.Shirts, v2.Shirts as Shirts2
from (
    select *, (select count(*) from view_1 t1 
        where t1.ClothingID <= t.ClothingID) as row
    from view_1 t
) v1
full outer join (
    select *, (select count(*) from view_2 t2 
        where t2.ClothingID <= t.ClothingID) as row
    from view_2 t
) v2 on v1.row = v2.row
```

**Added** after comment:

I've noticed and corrected mistake in preceding query.

I'll try to explain a bit. First of all we'll have to add a row numbers to both views to make sure that there are no gaps in id's. This is quite simple way:

```
select *, (select count(*) from view_1 t1 
    where t1.ClothingID <= t.ClothingID) as row
from view_1 t
```

This consist of two things, simple query selecting rows(*):

```
select *
from view_1 t
```

and [correlated subquery (read more on wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
(
    select count(*)
    from view_1 t1
    where t1.ClothingID <= t.ClothingID
) as row
```

This counts for each row of outer query (here it's (*)) preceding rows including self. So you might say count all rows which have `ClothingID` less or equal like current row for each row in view. For unique `ClothingID` (that I've assumed) it gives you row numbering (ordered by `ClothingID`).

Live example on [data.stackexchange.com - row numbering](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60966/row-numbering).

After that we can use both subqueries with row numbers to join them ([`full outer join` on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join)), live example on [data.stackexchange.com - merge two unrelated views](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60968/merge-two-unrelated-views-into-a-single-view).

Comment: I'll try this, seems like my only hope :)

Comment: @user519753 I've added alternative query for PostgreSQL lower than 8.4.

Comment: `t1.ClothingID <= t.ClothingID` I still don't understand what `t.ClothingID` is for, it's not t1 for table 1 or t2 for table 2, so what does it represent? Also thanks for going in depth with the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

If the views are unrelated, SQL will struggle to deal with it. You can do it, but there's a better and simpler way...

I suggest merging them *one after the other*, rather than *side-by-side* as you have suggested, ie a *union* rather than a *join*:

```
select 'view1' as source, ClothingID, Shoes, Shirts
from view1
union all
select 'view2', ClothingID, Shoes, Shirts
from view2
```

This would be the usual approach for this kind of situation, and is simple to code and understand.

Note the use of `UNION ALL`, which preserves row order as selected and does not remove duplicates, as opposed to `UNION`, which sorts the rows and removes duplicates.

#### Edited

Added a column indicating which view the row came from.

Comment: `UNION ALL` does not necessarily preserve row order. It just does not remove any duplicates (usually DBMSes concatenate results but they are not required to). Note that with a compound SELECT statement LIKE this, you can put only the ORDER BY clause at the end, not in the subparts.

Comment: @Benoit They may not be *required* to deliver the rows in the order selected, but in 20 years of working with DBs I have yet to ever see union all execute any other way.

Comment: I have seen it Yesterday (Oracle). `WITH x AS (SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ... /* ZERO order by here */) SELECT * FROM x` gave me scrambled results.

Comment: it's not delivering me separate columns, so if the data gets pushed into the same columns and that the data is unrelated I won't be able to tell them apart in a `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1):

You could use Rownumber as a join parameter, and 2 temp tables?

So something like:

```
    Insert @table1
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Clothing_ID ASC) [Row_ID], Clothing_ID, Shoes, Shirts)
    FROM Table1 

    Insert @table2
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Clothing_ID ASC)[RowID], Clothing_ID, Shoes, Shirts)
    FROM Table2

    Select  t1.Clothing_ID, t2.Clothing_ID,t1.Shoes,t2.Shoes, t1.Shirts,t2.Shirts
    from @table1 t1
    JOIN atable2 t2 on t1.Row_ID = t2.Row_ID
```

I think that should be roughly sensible.  Make sure you are using the correct join so the full output for both queries appear

e;fb

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT row_number() over(), * FROM table1) t1
FULL JOIN (SELECT row_number() over(), * FROM table2) t2 using(row_number)
```